# Reduce EBS root device size

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I want to reduce the size of the root volume of a Windows server EC2 instance .

1) Stop the running instance (instance 1)

2) Detach its root EBS device

3) Create new instance with any volume (instance 2)

4) Mount the detached volume to new instance as to be seen as secondary volume

5) Shrink the volume

6) Detach it after shrinking

7) mounting to the instance 1

8)Start the instance 1

Are steps above the frequent ones to be followed to achieve this purpose ?
Are there any other methods ?

Comment: Define "*safe*".  Is it possible to mess up and trash your instance?  Yes, it is; do a snapshot first.  But it's the normal procedure for doing what you want to do.  Sysadmins do stuff like this all the time, which is why we're so fond of frequent, well-tested backups.

Comment: Thank you for your response . I have added more clarity on my question

Comment: Ok thank you . Just last question : When you shrink the volume you must have in the end only 1 volume (the resized one) and the remaining size must appear as unused (unformatted ) ?

Comment: Your original question was "I'm doing X, is this safe", which I tried to answer.  You now seem to want a step-by-step validation of your approach, which as a non-Windows user, I'm afraid I can't give you.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the size of the partition using the steps you provide should work.

However you will be left with unallocated space at the end of the volume. You could create another partition in this space if you wanted.

It is not possible to reduce the size of the EBS volume.

If you volume was a data volume, you could create another smaller volume and copy the data over. But I don't think this would work for a Windows boot volume.